# Unable to Store data in order placed table and deleting data from cart table after completion of payment

Tags: python, django, razorpay

4

i am using razorpay payment gateway web integration for my learning eccomerce project everyhing work fine payment can be done all i want is to store my cart data in OrderPlaced table and delete the cart data from Carts table and redirect the page on home after payment done in my order model using test mode.
but in this code something is wrong after payment completion Nothing happen no changes nor in Carts table neither in OrderPlaced table.
This is my Checkout View for the payment initiation

```
class checkout(View):
    def get(self, request):
        user = request.user
        add = Customer.objects.filter(user=user)
        cart_items = Cart.objects.filter(user=user)
        famount = 0
        for p in cart_items:
            value = p.quantity*p.product.discounted_price
            famount = famount+value
        totalamount = famount+30
        razoramount = int(totalamount * 100)
        client = razorpay.Client(
            auth=(settings.RAZOR_KEY_ID, settings.RAZOR_KEY_SECRET))
        data = {"amount": razoramount, "currency": "INR",
                "receipt": "order_rcptid_12"}
        payment_response = client.order.create(data=data)
        print(payment_response)

        order_id = payment_response['id']
        order_status = payment_response['status']
        if order_status == 'created':
            payment = Payment(
                user=user,
                amount=totalamount,
                razorpay_order_id=order_id,
                razorpay_payment_status=order_status
            )
            payment.save()

        return render(request, 'app/checkout.html', locals())
```

And this is my paymentDone View here i try to store all cart items in OrderPlace table and delete item from the Cart table..

```
def payment_done(request):
    order_id = request.GET.get('order_id')
    payment_id = request.GET.get('payment_id')
    cust_id = request.GET.get('cust_id')
    user = request.user
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=cust_id)
    payment = Payment.objects.get(razorpay_order_id=order_id)
    payment.paid = True
    payment.razorpay_payment_id = payment_id
    payment.save()

    cart = Cart.objects.filter(user=user)
    for c in cart:
        OrderPlaced(user=user, customer=customer, product=c.product,
                    quantity=c.quantity, payment=payment).save()
        c.delete()
    return redirect("orders")
```

And these Are my Models for the payment and OrderPlaced tabe and Cart tabel..

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    @property
    def total_cost(self):
        return self.quantity * self.product.discounted_price


class Payment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    razorpay_order_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    razorpay_payment_status = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    razorpay_payment_id = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)


STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('Accepted', 'Accepted'),
    ('Packed', 'Packed'),
    ('On The way', 'On The Way'),
    ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
    ('Cancel', 'Cancel'),
    ('Pending', 'Pending'),
)


class OrderPlaced(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='Pending')
    payment = models.ForeignKey(Payment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")

    @property
    def total_cost(self):
        return self.quantity*self.product.discounted_price
```

Any Idea What i am Doing worng??

i want is to store my cart data in OrderPlaced table and delete the cart data from Carts table and redirect the page on home after payment done in my order model using test mode. this code make payment successfully but not success in placing Order...